# Printing all the plots in a loop using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to implement random walk in python using the below code:

```
sigma = 0.5
mu = 0.1
N=2
T=10
delta_t=np.array([0.5,0.1,0.05,0.01])
delta_x = np.sqrt(delta_t)
# print(delta_x[2])


for ite in range(0, len(delta_t)):
    u = (sigma**2 + mu*delta_x[ite])/2
    d = (sigma**2 - mu*delta_x[ite])/2
    m = int(10/delta_t[ite])


    prob =[u,u+d,1]

    start = 0
    final_positions = []

    for i in range(N):
        downp = []
        upp = []
        samep = []
        positions = [start]

        for i in range(m):
            rand = np.random.random()
            upp.append(rand < prob[0])
            downp.append(rand >prob[0] and rand <=prob[1])
            samep.append(rand > prob[1] and rand <= prob[2])
        for idownp, iupp, isamep in zip(downp, upp, samep):
            down = idownp 
            up = iupp
            same = isamep 
            positions.append(positions[-1] - down*delta_x[ite] + up*delta_x[ite])
        plt.plot(positions)
```

I want to plot all the possible walks (in this case 4 as per the outer loop). However, I am able to print only the last one. Can someone help in printing out all the possible walks in this case?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood by your question, just add a

```
plt.show()
```

after the plt.plot() and you will get seperate graphs rather then all merged into one.